# Find three points given three lines and some conditions

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles

Let $L$ be the line $2y=x+4$, $M$ be the line $x+y=4$, $N$ be the line $y+8=3x$. Find points $u,v,w\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that, in the triangle $[u,v,w]$, $L$ is the angle bisector at $u$, $M$ is the altitude from $v$, $N$ is the median from $w$.

My attempt:

> - $u$ lies on $L$, so $u=(2t,t+4)$ for some $t\in\mathbb{R}$
> - $w$ lies on $N$, so $w=(q, 3q-8)$ for some $q\in\mathbb{R}$
> - $v$ lies on $M$, so $v=(s, 4-s)$ for some $s\in\mathbb{R}$
> - Some point on $v-w$ lies on $M$, so $3t=4q-8$ (after substituting the coordinates of $v-w$ into the linear equation for $M$.

Now the problem is that I don't know how to utilize the condition for $L$ being the angle bisector at $u$ and the condition $M$ being the altitude from $v$ without introducing additional variables.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained bellow, I've found the following points: 
$$u=(12,8),\qquad v=(-2,6),\qquad w=(2,-2).  $$
The associated [position vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_(vector)) are:
$$\mathbf{u}=12\,\mathbf{\hat{e}}_{1}+8\,\mathbf{\hat{e}}_{2} ,\quad \mathbf{v}=-2\,\mathbf{\hat{e}}_{1}+6\,\mathbf{\hat{e}}_{2},\quad \mathbf{w}=2\,\mathbf{\hat{e}}_{1}-2\,\mathbf{\hat{e}}_{2} . $$

Triangle $[u,v,w]=[(12,8),(-2,6),(2,-2)]$  and lines $L$ (black), $M$ (blue) and   $N$ (red)
[image]

As it has already been pointed out, instead of

> - $u$ lies on $L$, so $u=(2t,t+4)$ for some $t\in\mathbb{R}$

it should be

- $u$ lies on $L$, so $u=(2t,t+2)$ for some $t\in\mathbb{R}$,

because if we replace $x$ with $2t$ in $2y=x+4$, we obtain $2y=2t+4$, which means that $y=t+2$.

After this correction, your system of three equations becomes

$$u=(2t,t+4)\tag{1} ,$$
$$v=(s,4-s)\tag{2} ,$$
$$w=(q,3q-8)\tag{3} .$$

The position vectors are thus
$$\mathbf{u}=(2t)\,\mathbf{\hat{e}_1}+(t+4)\,\mathbf{\hat{e}_2}\tag{1$\mathrm{a}$},$$
$$\mathbf{v}=s\,\mathbf{\hat{e}_1}+(4-s)\,\mathbf{\hat{e}_2}\tag{2$\mathrm{a}$},$$
$$\mathbf{w}=q\,\mathbf{\hat{e}_1}+(3q-8)\,\mathbf{\hat{e}_2}\tag{3$\mathrm{a}$}.$$

> Now the problem is that I don't know how to utilize the condition for $L$ being the angle bisector at $u$ and the condition $M$ being the altitude from $v$ without introducing additional variables.

To obtain **additional relations between $t,s$ and $q$, such as equations $(5')$, $(7')$ and $(15)$, without introducing additional variables, except the angles between the bisector $L$ and the two sides $[u,v]$ and $[u,w]$, we compute their [slopes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope)** and use the conditions on $L,M,N$:

> (a) $L$ is the angle bisector at $u$,
>
> (b) $M$ is the altitude from $v$,
>
> (c) $N$ is the median from $w$.

1. As for $M: x+y=4$, since its slope is $-1$ and it is is perpendicular to the vector
   $$\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{u}=(q-2t)\,\mathbf{\hat{e}}_{1}+(3q-t-10)\,\mathbf{\hat{e}}_{2}\tag{4},$$
   by $(\mathrm{D})$ bellow, the slope of $\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{u}$ should be $1$. Then
   $$ 3q-t-10=q-2t\Leftrightarrow 2q+t-10=0.\tag{5} $$
   Solving $(5)$ for $q$, we obtain 
   $$q=-\frac{1}{2}t+5.\tag{5'}$$ 
   Substituting $(5')$ in $(3)$, we obtain
   $$w=\left(-\frac{1}{2}t+5,-\frac{3}{2}t+7\right)\tag{3'}$$
2. As for $N:$ $y+8=3x$, its intersection with the side $\left[ u,v\right] $ is
   the point
   $$\frac{u+v}{2}=\frac{(2t,t+2)+(s,4-s)}{2}=\left( \frac{1}{2}s+t,-\frac{1}{2}s+
   \frac{1}{2}t+3\right).\tag{6} $$
   Replacing $x$ with $\frac{1}{2}s+t$ and $y$ with $-\frac{1}{2}s+\frac{1}{2}t+3$  in the equation $y+8=3x$, we obtain 
   $$\left( -\frac{1}{2}s+\frac{1}{2}t+3\right) +8=3\left( \frac{1}{2}s+t\right).\tag{7}$$
   Solving for $s$, we obtain
   $$s=\frac{11}{2}-\frac{5}{4}t.\tag{7'}$$
   Now, substituting $(7')$ in $(2)$, we obtain
   $$v=\left(-\frac{5}{4}t+\frac{11}{2},\frac{5}{4}t-\frac{3}{2}\right).\tag{2'}$$
3. As for $L:2y=x+4$, we now use this equation to find the acute angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ between $L$ and, respectively, the sides $[u,v]$ and $[u,w]$. These angles satisfy the condition
   $$\theta_1=\theta_2.\tag{8} $$
   The slope $m$ of $L$ is 
   $$m=\frac{1}{2}.\tag{9}$$
   Also, let $m_1$ and $m_2$ be, respectively, the slopes of the sides $[u,v]$ and $[u,w]$. The vectors $\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{u}$ and  $\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{u}$ are parallel, respectively, to $[u,v]$ and $[u,w]$.
   Combining $(2'),(1), (2\mathrm{a}), (1\mathrm{a})$, we have
   $$
   \mathbf{v}-\mathbf{u}=\left( -\frac{13}{4}t+\frac{11}{2}\right)\, \mathbf{\hat{e}}_{1}+\left( \frac{1}{4}t-\frac{7}{2}\right)\, \mathbf{\hat{e}}_{2}\tag{4'}
   $$
   Let's denote its slope by
   $$
   m_{1}=\frac{t/4-7/2}{-13t/4+11/2}=\frac{14-t}{13t-22}\tag{10}.
   $$
   Similarly, from $(4),(5')$, we obtain
   $$
   \mathbf{w}-\mathbf{u}=\left( -\frac{5}{2}t+5\right)\, \mathbf{\hat{e}}_{1}+\left( -\frac{5}{2}t+5\right)\, \mathbf{\hat{e}}_{2},\tag{11}
   $$
   whose slope is denoted by
   $$
   m_{2}=\frac{-5t/2+5}{-5/2t+5}=1.\tag{12}
   $$
   We now apply twice the formula $(\mathrm{C})$ bellow, one for the lines with slopes $m$ and $m'=m_1$, and another for the lines with slopes $m$ and $m'=m_2$:
   \begin{equation*}
   \tan \theta_1 =\left|\frac{m-m_1}{1+mm_1}\right|,\tag{$\mathrm{C_1}$}
   \end{equation*}
   \begin{equation*}
   \tan \theta_2 =\left|\frac{m-m_2}{1+mm_2}\right|.\tag{$\mathrm{C_2}$}
   \end{equation*}
   From $(8)$ we should have
   \begin{equation*}
   \tan \theta_1 =\tan \theta_2 \Leftrightarrow\left|\frac{m-m_1}{1+mm_1}\right| =\left|\frac{m-m_2}{1+mm_2}\right|.\tag{$\mathrm{C_3}$}
   \end{equation*}
   Equivalently,
   \begin{equation*}
   \left\vert \left( m-m_{1}\right) \left( 1+mm_{2}\right) \right\vert
   =\left\vert \left( m-m_{2}\right) \left( 1+mm_{1}\right) \right\vert .\tag{13}
   \end{equation*}
   For $m=\frac{1}{2}$ and $m_{2}=1$, we obtain 
   \begin{equation*}
   \frac{3}{2}\left\vert \frac{1}{2}-m_{1}\right\vert =\frac{1}{2}\left\vert 1+
   \frac{1}{2}m_{1}\right\vert .\tag{14}
   \end{equation*}
   The possible solutions are
   \begin{equation*}
   \frac{14-t}{13t-22}=m_{1}=1\qquad \text{or}\qquad \frac{14-t}{13t-22}=m_{1}=
   \frac{1}{7};\tag{15}
   \end{equation*}
   the corresponding possible values of $t$ being
   \begin{equation*}
   t=\frac{18}{7}\qquad \text{or}\qquad t=6.\tag{16}
   \end{equation*}
   Using equations $\left( 1\right) ,\left( 2^{\prime }\right) $ and $\left( 3^{\prime }\right) $, for $t=\frac{18}{7}$, we obtain the points $$u=\left( \frac{36}{7},\frac{32}{7}\right) ,\qquad v=\left( \frac{16}{7},\frac{12}{7}\right) ,\qquad w=\left( \frac{26}{7},\frac{22}{7}\right) ,\tag{17}$$ which are colinear; for $t=6$, we obtain the vertices $u,v$ and $w$ indicated in the beginning:
   $$u=(12,8),\qquad v=(-2,6),\qquad w=(2,-2).  \tag{18}$$

**Acute angle $\theta$ between two lines with slopes $m$ and $m'$ using trigonometry (angle difference identity for tangent)** $[1]$

If $\alpha $ is the angle that a line with slope $m$ makes with the $x$-axis
and $\alpha ^{\prime }$ is the angle that another line with slope $m^{\prime
}$ makes with the $x$-axis, then, assuming that $\alpha\ge\alpha'$, the acute angle $\theta $ between the two
lines is given by

\begin{equation*}
\theta =\alpha -\alpha ^{\prime }\qquad \text{or}\qquad \theta =\pi -\left(
\alpha -\alpha ^{\prime }\right),\quad 0\le\theta\le \frac{\pi}{2}.\tag{$\mathrm{A}$} 
\end{equation*}

Consequently,

\begin{equation*}
\tan \theta =\tan \left( \alpha -\alpha ^{\prime }\right) \qquad \text{
or }\qquad\tan \theta =-\tan \left( \alpha -\alpha ^{\prime }\right). \tag{$\mathrm{B}$}
\end{equation*}

From [trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities), we know that

\begin{equation*}
\tan \theta =\tan \left( \alpha -\alpha ^{\prime }\right) =\frac{\tan \alpha
-\tan \alpha ^{\prime }}{1+\tan \alpha \tan \alpha ^{\prime }}
\end{equation*}

Since

\begin{equation*}
m=\tan \alpha \qquad\text{ and }\qquad m^{\prime }=\tan \alpha 
\end{equation*}

we obtain

\begin{equation*}
\tan \theta =\left|\frac{m-m^{\prime }}{1+mm^{\prime }}\right|,\qquad 0\le\theta \le\frac{\pi}{2}.\tag{$\mathrm{C}$}
\end{equation*}

If $\alpha <\alpha'$, this equation is still valid, because its right-hand side is non-negative.

In particular, if $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$,the denominator should satisfy the well known equation

\begin{equation*}
mm^{\prime }=-1.\tag{$\mathrm{D}$}
\end{equation*}

$[1]$ J. Sebastião e Silva, "Geometria Analítica Plana", pp. 76-77, 1967

Comment: So, upon correcting my answer thanks to your signalling, I completed the calculations and reached to your same result (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Just to better clarify the vectorial approach in writing down the last two conditions given in *AnuragA* answer, hoping you have a basic knowledge of vectors.

Given a line written as $ax+by+c=0$, you know that you can rewrite it as $a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)=0$, where $P_0=(x_0,y_0)$ is a point on the line.
Then indicating by $X=(x,y)$ a generic point on the line, the line equation becomes $(a,b)\cdot \mathop {P_0 X}\limits^ \to=0$. So all segments on the line are, and therefore the line is, normal to $(a,b)$, i.e. parallel to $(b,-a)$.

That premised,
 1) $N$ median from $w \quad \Rightarrow \quad w \in N ,\; (u+v)/2 \in N$

2) $\mathop {uw}\limits^ \to \bot M \quad \Rightarrow \quad (q-2t,\;3q-t-10) \cdot(1,\;-1)=0$
3) $L$ bisects $\angle  (\mathop {uv}\limits^ \to,\mathop {uw}\limits^ \to)\quad \Rightarrow \quad (-2,\,-1)=\lambda(\mathop {uv}\limits^ \to /|\mathop {uv}\limits^ \to| +\mathop {uw}\limits^ \to / |\mathop {uw}\limits^ \to|)$

As you see no further variable is introduced, once you get rid of $\lambda$ by dividing the components (if not null).

To complete the task as to check the results, let's proceed.
You already rightly found that for each point to lie on the respective line, we shall have
this parametric representation (corrected concerning $u$, as already indicated by *Américo*)
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\left\{ \matrix{
  u = \left( {2t,t + 2} \right) \hfill \cr 
  w = \left( {q,3q - 8} \right) \hfill \cr 
  v = \left( {s,4 - s} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right.
 } \tag{1}$$

The three conditions indicated above, then translates into
(the condition $w \in N$ is already satisfied)
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\left\{ \matrix{
  {{t + 2 + 4 - s} \over 2} + 8 = 3{{2t + s} \over 2}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad 5t + 4s = 22 \hfill \cr 
  q - 2t - 3q + t + 10 = 0\quad  \Rightarrow \quad t + 2q = 10 \hfill \cr 
  \left( { - 2, - 1} \right) = \lambda \left( {{{\left( {s - 2t,\; - t - s + 2} \right)} \over {\sqrt {\left( {s - 2t} \right)^{\,2}  + \left( { - t - s + 2} \right)^{\,2} } }} + {{\left( {q - 2t,\;3q - t - 10} \right)} \over {\sqrt {\left( {q - 2t} \right)^{\,2}  + \left( {3q - t - 10} \right)^{\,2} } }}} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right.
 } \tag{2}$$

Using the first two to express $s$ and $q$ in terms of $t$, and replacing that in the third equation
after some simple manipulations we get
$$
\left( { - 2, - 1} \right) = \lambda \left( {{{\left( {22 - 13t,\; - 14 + t} \right)} \over {\sqrt {\left( {22 - 13t} \right)^{\,2}  + \left( { - 14 + t} \right)^{\,2} } }} + {{\left( {1,\;1} \right)} \over {\sqrt 2 }}} \right)
$$
that is
$$
\eqalign{
  & 2 = \left( {{{{{\left( {22 - 13t} \right)} \over {\sqrt {\left( {22 - 13t} \right)^{\,2}  + \left( { - 14 + t} \right)^{\,2} } }} + {1 \over {\sqrt 2 }}} \over {{{\left( {\; - 14 + t} \right)} \over {\sqrt {\left( {22 - 13t} \right)^{\,2}  + \left( { - 14 + t} \right)^{\,2} } }} + {1 \over {\sqrt 2 }}}}} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {{{\sqrt 2 \left( {22 - 13t} \right) + \sqrt {170\,t^{\,2}  - 600t + 680} } \over {\sqrt 2 \left( {\; - 14 + t} \right) + \sqrt {170\,t^{\,2}  - 600t + 680} }}} \right) \cr} 
$$

then
$$
\sqrt {5\left( {17\,t^{\,2}  - 60t + 68} \right)}  = \left( {22 - 13t} \right) - 2\left( {\; - 14 + t} \right) = 5\left( {10 - 3t} \right)
$$
and finally
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
7t^{\,2}  - 60t + 108 = 0
 } $$
which provides two values for $t$ 
$$
t = 18/7,\quad t = 6
$$

The first is to be discarded, since when replaced in the third equation gives $2=1$. So we are left with $t=6$.

Consequently, $q=2$ and $s=-2$ and finally we get the three points as:
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\left\{ \matrix{
  u = \left( {12,\;8} \right) \hfill \cr 
  w = \left( {2,\; - 2} \right) \hfill \cr 
  v = \left( { - 2,\;6} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right.
 } \tag{3}$$

which  **confirms *Américo's* answer** .

Comment: Instead of $$(1,\,-2)=\lambda(\mathop {uv}\limits^ \to /|\mathop {uv}\limits^ \to| +\mathop {uw}\limits^ \to / |\mathop {uw}\limits^ \to|)$$ shouldn't it be, for instance, $$(-4,\,-2)=\lambda(\mathop {uv}\limits^ \to /|\mathop {uv}\limits^ \to| +\mathop {uw}\limits^ \to / |\mathop {uw}\limits^ \to|)$$

Comment: @yes, you are right: I mistook parallel/normal vector to the lines: thanks for signalling.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** 
Your point $u$ is incorrect. It should be $u=(2t,t+\color{red}{2})$.

Treating the points $u,v,w$ as position vectors, we can get
$$\overline{uv}=(s,4-s)-(2t,t+\color{red}{2})=(s-2t, \color{red}{2-s-t}).$$
Likewise
$$\overline{uw}=(q,3q-8)-(2t,t+\color{red}{2})=(q-2t, \color{red}{3q-t-10}).$$
The midpoint of the side represented by the vector $\overline{uv}$, call it $A$, is given by $\left(\frac{s+2t}{2},\frac{\color{red}{6-s+t}}{2}\right)$.

Now observe the following:

1. The mid-point $A$ should lie on the line $N$ because $N$ is the median from $w$. So it's coordinates should satisfy the equation for $N$.
2. The side represented by $\overline{uw}$ is perpendicular to the line $M$ because $M$ is the altitude friom $v$. Therefore the product of the slopes should be $-1$.
3. For $L$ being the bisector we need: angle between $\overline{uv}$ and $L$ should be equal to the angle between $\overline{uw}$ and L.

If you can set up these three equations, you will have the values of the three unknowns.

Comment: I would suggest , for 2) to put to $0$ the dot product of $\overline{uw}$ and tangent vector to line $M$; for 3) to put that tangent vector to $L$ be parallel to the sum of the unit vectors $\overline{uv} \, / \, |\overline{uv}|$ and $\overline{uw} \, / \, |\overline{uw}|$

Comment: @GCab that is definitely a good approach. But I was not sure how familiar OP was with the language of vectors and that is why I refrained (as much as I could) from using the vectorial language.

Comment: How do I do a dot product of the vector tangent to $M$ with $\overline{uw}$ without introducing new variables? Or, likewise, how does one create an equation of $\overline{uw}$ with line $M$ so that the product of the slopes is $-1$? Also, how does one create the equation in (3)? Again, to consider the equality of the angles, one would need to introduce new variables, right?

Comment: @sequence see my answer, it has already been computed, try looking for what position vector means. If not, then using basic defintion of the slope we get the slope of line joining $u$ and $v$ is $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{-s-t}{s-2t}$ . Slope of $M$ is $-1$. Now you take their product...

Comment: @AnuragA Thanks. Can you please clarify how to build a vectorial equation for this?

Comment: @sequence there is no need to make a vector equation. If you are unfamiliar with it then just use the basic definitions from analytic geometry (like I stated in my comment). Moreover the outline I have suggested in my answer doesn't need much language from the vectors.

Comment: @AnuragA I'm OK with vectors, but I don't see how to do the $0$ dot product without introducing new variables. That is, how do we define the line $M$ in vector form?

Comment: Also, from the slope equation (2) we get $t=2s$, and this, in conjunction with $t=\frac{24}5 - \frac{4s}5$ gives $t=\frac{24}7$, but this then will not give the correct $u$ (does not match the answer).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61084/discussion-between-anurag-a-and-sequence).

Comment: @AnuragA, yes it seems  you are right, since *sequence* is asking how to find the parallel vector to $M$. However, I cannot conceive how to properly study analytic geometry without vectors ( orientated segments).

Comment: @AnuragA this $t$ doesn't give the correct answer. And if it did, then we wouldn't even need to bother with the angle bisector, since we could easily find $s$ and $q$ as well without it.

Comment: @sequence I think I just continued with your work and made the same error as you did. The line that is perpendicular to $M$ is $uw$ and not $uv$. So if you do the slope thing, then you get the equation: $2q+t=10$. By putting point $A$ in line $N$ we get $4s+5t=22$. So you still need one more equation and that will come from the bisector condition. There doesn't seem to be anything incorrect in the steps I have outlined. So it will work.